# How often did the SG-1 team members use a Sarcophagus?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-movie

Do we have any idea how many times each of the main SG-1 team members (Jack, Daniel, Sam, Teal'c, Jonas, Cameron, Vala) used a Sarcophagus?

I'm interested in answers from all *official* sources, but focused only on events that actually happened in the main timeline (so, excluding incidents in dreams, alternate timelines, duplicates, etc).

Comment: @Paulie_D: Why? Is die to the number of novels? After all I cannot believe that a Sarcophagus would show up that often in them. Also I do not remember and usage in the games or in RPGs. Should I have asked for a list of novels where a Sarcophagus appears and do the count on my own? But then list question are a no-no.

Comment: "Non-canon sources" would include anything ever written about _SG-1_, including fan fiction scribbled on the back of a napkin. The canon sources may be a large set, but relatively small and much easier to find than all possible non-canon sources. My advice would be to remove "non-canon" from your question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is genuinely that we can't give a precise number. In the Season 2 episode "Need", Daniel repeatedly uses the Sarcophagus over the course of (I think) several days, and we can't really be sure how many times he used it per day, or for how long, etc, just that he did and it didn't end well. I know that on a couple of occasions Jack and Teal'c have also used them to survive otherwise certain death. In fact, I think Sam is the only original SG-1 member to have NOT used a Sarcophagus.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I've edited to reflect that asking for all sources (canon & non-canon) has resulted in the question being downvoted and closed.

Comment: Jack was forced to use it also when B'all was death torturing him to extract information from him. Jack was killed and revived continuously and was slowly getting his mind cracked.  It wasn't said how many times during that period but was 10's or more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's impossible to say with complete certainty, but this is what we can do:

### Daniel: 11+

1. In the original *Stargate* film, Daniel is placed in a Sarcophagus by Ra after being killed by a Jaffa guard
2. In the season 2 premiere, "The Serpent's Lair, Part 2", Daniel places himself inside Klorel's Sarcophagus after once again being shot by a Jaffa
3. In the season 2 episode "Need", SG-1 is enslaved by a malicious native population and put to work in a mine. Daniel is badly wounded by a guard, and is placed in a Sarcophagus by Shyla, the planet's princess, who's taken a fancy to him
4. Later in "Need", Daniel is again persuaded into the Sarcophagus by Shyla, this time to heal him of some imagined injury
5. Later still in "Need", he remarks that he's used it "nine or ten" times:

   > **Daniel:**  Look, if we do this right we'll have access to all the naquadah and the sarcophagus.
   >
   > **Sam:** How many times have you used it?
   >
   > **Daniel:** I don't know; nine or ten.
   >
   > <sup>*Stargate SG-1* Season 2 Episode 5: "Need"</sup>

   Assuming he's counting the two times I counted above, that gives a lower bound of seven additional usages. He may or may not use it again after this, but we can't be certain.

### Jack: 4+

In the season 6 episode "Abyss", Jack is captured by Ba'al and tortured; Ba'al tortures him to death and then revives him in a Sarcophagus. We see Jack coming out of it at least three times:

- After Jack (inhabited by the Tok'ra Kanan) is initially shot trying to escape Ba'al's stronghold world
- Just before Jack is first led into his cell, and encounters Daniel
- In a scene just after Hammond refuses to mount an armed assault on Ba'al's outpost

Dialogue from Ba'al confirms a fourth occasion shortly after this, though we don't actually see Jack enter or exit the Sarcophagus:

> **Ba'al:** Your mind is beginning to fail. It's time for the sarcophagus
>
> <sup>*Stargate SG-1* Season 6 Episode 6: "Abyss"</sup>

And dialogue from Daniel suggests there were more occasions that weren't directly confirmed:

> **Daniel:** How many times has it been already? It can regenerate your body, make you strong enough to go through that all over again, but all the time, it's destroying who you are.
>
> <sup>*Stargate SG-1* Season 6 Episode 6: "Abyss"</sup>

### Vala: Unknown, possibly many

We learn in her very first appearance that Vala was formerly host to a Goa'uld symbiote (later identified as [Qetesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qetesh)):

> **Daniel:** You're a Goa'uld.
>
> **Vala:** No. But I was once a host to one.
>
> <sup>*Stargate SG-1* Season 8 Episode 12: "Promethus Unbound"</sup>

Since we don't know how long she was a host for, or how often a regular Goa'uld uses their Sarcophagus, it's impossible to say exactly how many times Vala went inside of one; if she was a host for any significant length of time, though, presumably there were many occasions.

### Teal'c: 1+

We only know that Teal'c used a Sarcophagus once, in the season 5 premiere "Enemies"; he reveals as much to Jack:

> **Jack:** You made it!
>
> **Teal'c:** Apophis revived me in a sarcophagus. We fled his ship when the replicators attacked.
>
> <sup>*Stargate SG-1* Season 5 Episode 1: "Enemies"</sup>

Although we later learn that Teal'c is under Apophis' influence, and could be lying, the last time we see him (in the season 4 finale), he takes a staff weapon blast to the back; it seems likely that he's telling the truth.

It's possible that he had other occasion to use the Sarcophagus in his position as Apophis' First Prime, though I admit that seems unlikely.

### Sam, Jonas, and Cam: 0 known

There are no known instances of any of these characters using a Sarcophagus.

Cam, of course, wasn't anything more than a pilot until after the Goa'uld had been eliminated as a credible galactic threat; he had no opportunity to be in the vicinity of one.

Jonas was only on the team for a short time, and well after the addictive effects of the Sarcophagus were known by Stargate Command.

Sam, presumably, was just lucky.

Although I don't have a great familiarity with the *Stargate* novels, a cursory Google suggests no additional Sarcophagus trips by SG-1 in any of them; I am, of course, welcome to being corrected.

Comment: Vala's father was still alive and age appropriate so presumably her lifespan had not been unnaturally extended.

Answer (score 1):

Jack was also placed in Hathor's sarcophagus in the season one episode "Hathor", after she attempted to convert him into a Jaffa. That sarcophagus was destroyed shortly after.

Comment: Although you're not wrong, this probably would have been better as a comment on the answer above.